# detecting call with which number ended when there are multiple calls in progress using Android Telephony framework

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I am using PhoneStateListener and overriding onCallStateChanged() function.
B called A .. I could observe the incoming number being passed to onCallStateChanged().
state here is CALL_STATE_RINGING .. after call is accepted..we go to CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK state.
C called A .. I could observe the incoming number being passed to onCallStateChanged() function.
I could observe  CALL_STATE_RINGING and after the call is accepted.. we go to CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK.
Now we swapped the call to B and we ended the call with B.

I would like to find out which among the two calls ended. 
I wouldn't be able to use the CALL_STATE_IDLE here to track it because, there is another active call in progress whent he call ended.
CALL_STATE_OFF_HOOK wouldn't serve my purpose. 
Please guide me how to proceed tacking this problem.